# Does PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey have (or even need) a public key equivalent?

Tags: c, openssl, libcrypto

`libcrypto3` provides a `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey` as shown here

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey.html

I do not see a `PEM_read_bio_PublicKey`. There *is* a `PEM_read_PUBKEY`, but it expects a `FILE*` and not a BIO.

Obviously algorithm-specific read functions exist, but why is there no `PEM_read_bio_PublicKey`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually called `PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY`, listed in the same man page:

```
 EVP_PKEY *PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(BIO *bp, EVP_PKEY **x,
                               pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);
```

Comment: That does look to be it, thank you. The naming conventions don't follow patterns I'd expect.

Comment: Plus: Apologies for my missing that, and I appreciate you answering regardless.

Comment: Sage: with a handful of exceptions PEM routine names are `PEM_{read|write}[_bio]_<datatype>` (using fp if you omit _bio) while DER are `{d2i|i2d}_<datatype>[_{bio|fp}]` (using memory if you omit both _bio _fp)